# C++ Iterator access next element for comparison

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to compare two elements in a List by 'peeking' into the next element in the list. Using C++11.

Is this possible? I'm having some trouble.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    list<int> intList;

    intList.push_back(10);
    intList.push_back(20);
    intList.push_back(30);
    intList.push_back(30);


    list<int>::iterator it;

    for (it = intList.begin(); it != intList.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it == *it + 1)
            cout << "Duplicate: " << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're dereferencing `it` and then adding 1 to it. Try `*std::next(it)`.

Comment: Or just `*(it + 1)` which is not the same as `*it + 1` which means `(*it) + 1`

Comment: @immibis Wouldn't work with `std::list`. It's a `ForwardIterator`.

Comment: [`std::adjacent_find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) supports `ForwardIterator`.

Comment: aside from the technical issues, you can't dereference `end()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
assert(!intList.empty()); // else ++begin is UB

for (list<int>::iterator it1 = intList.begin(), it2 = ++intList.begin();
     it2 != intList.end(); ++it1, ++it2)
{
    if (*it1 == *it2)
        cout << "Duplicate: " << *it1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks John - What does UB mean?

Comment: @Chen: Undefined Behavior.  Stuff you must not do.

Answer (score 1):

Your search can be simplified by using [`std::adjacent_find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) instead (which supports `std::list` iterators):

> Searches the range `[first, last)` for two consecutive identical elements.

For example:

```
list<int>::iterator it = std::adjacent_find(intList.begin(), intList.end());
if (it != intList.end())
    cout << "Duplicate: " << *it << '\n';`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but your confronting `*it` with `*it` augmented by 1 (that is even different).

I suppose your intention was to confront two adiacent element of the list, so [thanks to DeiDei for the correction]

```
if ( false == intList.empty() )
 {
   auto it { intList.cbegin() };
   auto oldVal { *it };

   for ( ; ++it != intList.cend() ; oldVal = *it )
    {
      if ( *it == oldVal )
         cout << "Duplicate: " << oldVal << '\n';
    }
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: `*(it-1)` will not compile with a `std::list`.

Comment: @DeiDei: D'oh! You're right: It's a list. Thanks; I'll correct.